# Why are my executables being run as a domain user in IIS 6?

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, impersonation

I'm having problems with IIS in DEV vs QA. One thing I notices by watching task manager is that when a .exe runs on DEV it is running as the user instead of my generic iis user. Is this normal for IIS with integrated authentication or is there some other setting I need to look into?

Comment: When the page itself is an .exe so when the user performs an action it executes the exe

Comment: As in http://example.com/myapp.exe?x=1&v=3   ?

Comment: yes. When I have anonymous authentication enable and run the executable from the web the user is my generic iis_user account. When integrated authentication in enable it runs as my domain user account. I just wondered if that was normal.

Comment: When you say "DEV" do you mean running in Visual Studio or a DEV server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With integrated authentication, processes are launched as the logged in user. When anonymous integration is enabled the process are launched as the iis user. It is also possible to enable both at the same time.